# Problem implementing interfaces into a class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I defined two interfaces outside a class. Then I implemented the two interfaces and tried to set them to private properties of the class but there is still something wrong but I can't imagine what.

Could anybody help me with that?

[image]

There are no error messages out of the compiler, but VSCode reveals:

[image]

Comment: Please do not publish code images, much better is paste code into code block!

Comment: Haha I'm sorry but I thought it looks way better ;) Next time I'm going to use the code block feature ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have implemented 2 interfaces on Handler but have not created interface properties in your class. If you need to make a field optional you can do it like so. (just put a question mark after the key.)

```
interface Isize {
  width? : number;
  height? : number;
}
```

In below case you will not get an error.

```
class Handler implements Isize, Iposition {
  public x; 
  public y;
  public height;
  public width:;
  .......
  ........
  .........
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 2):

As the error message states: you need to implement the properties from the interfaces directly in the class.
In this case this means:

```
class Handler implements Isize, Iposition {
  public width: number;
  public height: number;
  public x: number;
  public y: number

  constructor(x, y) {
    this.width = 300;
    this.height = 450;

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh ok. But how can I access the properties later on. I mean if they are properties each it doesn't make a difference to implement them via interfaces, does it? I try to code as clean as possible and like to use typed based objects... Thank you very much :)

Comment: Sure it does, to access the object later on you could have `let position: Iposition = new Handler(10, 20);` where you can get the properties with `position.x` and `position.y`.
The object doesn't care that it *also* implements Iposition, but still is sure to have all the required x and y information.

Answer (score 1):

So, if you do not want change your class implementation, and you can change interfaces, you can use this:

```js
interface Isize {
  size: {
    width: number;
    height: number;
  };
}

interface Iposition {
  position: {
    x: number;
    y: number;
  }
}

class Handler implements Isize, Iposition {
  position: { x: number; y: number; };
  size: { width: number; height: number; };
}
```